# Convert Java Map<Obj1, Collection<Obj2>> to Map<Obj2, Collection<Obj1>>

Tags: java, guava

What would be a good practice to convert `Map<Obj1, Collection<Obj2>>` to `Map<Obj2, Collection<Obj1>>`?

I tried doing it with `MultiMap`.

```
    Map<Obj1, Collection<Obj2>> originalMap = ...;
    Multimap<Obj1, Obj2> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    originalMap.forEach(multiMap::putAll);
    Map<Obj2, Collection<Obj1>> convertedMap = Multimaps.invertFrom(multiMap, ArrayListMultimap.create()).asMap();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with Java 8 Streams;

```
Map<Obj1, List<Obj2>> originalMap = ...

Map<Obj2, List<Obj1>> reversedMap = originalMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(obj2s -> obj2s.getValue().stream()
                .map(obj2 -> Map.entry(obj2, obj2s.getKey())))
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getKey, 
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
                )
        );
```

The `fltMap` coverts `Map<Obj1, List<Obj2>>` into a tuple like `<Obj2, Obj1>`, then collect the result grouping by `Obj2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but could be even more straightforward if you used `Multimap` instead in the first place and

1. you don't need mutability,
2. you don't have nulls.

If that's the case, all you need is [`ImmutableMultimap#inverse()`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#inverse--):

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, String> originalMultimap = ImmutableListMultimap.of(
        1, "foo",
        1, "bar",
        2, "baz",
        42, "foo"
);
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Integer> convertedMap = originalMultimap.inverse();
System.out.println(convertedMap);   // {foo=[1, 42], bar=[1], baz=[2]}
```

I used `ImmutableListMultimap` instead of `ImmutableMultimap` because [docs encourage to do so](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html):

> Warning: avoid direct usage of `ImmutableMultimap` as a type (as with `Multimap` itself). Prefer subtypes such as `ImmutableSetMultimap` or `ImmutableListMultimap`, which have well-defined `equals(java.lang.Object)` semantics, thus avoiding a common source of bugs and confusion.